# chrome hover not dropping menu down

Tags: css, google-chrome

I cant figure out why this is not working on Chrome only, 
But the hover doesnt show `span.sub-menu-response`

```
.navbar .navbar-inner  .nav-collapse > ul > li > span.sub-menu-response {
display: none;
background: #F8F8F8;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
border: 1px solid #9da3a7;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 0px !important; 
left:-92px;

}

.navbar .navbar-inner  .nav-collapse > ul > li:hover > span.sub-menu-response {
display: block;
background: #F8F8F8;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
border: 1px solid #9da3a7;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 0px !important; 
left:-92px;
}
```

The outputted html

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">

 <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="brand visible-phone">
     Categories
</a>
    <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>*content*</li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>
        Start Shopping</span><span class="active_downarrow"></span></a>
            <span class="sub-menu-response"></span>
        </li>


        <li> *content*  </li>


        <li> *content*   </li>

        <li>*content*</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>


</div>
```

EDIT: Whats stranger is that if I put the `:hover` after `ul` instead of `li` it works.

Comment: A jsfiddle demo would be very useful in your case.

Comment: annoyingly it seems to work in a jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/9vFuk/

Comment: LOL! I hate this when it happens...

Comment: Does the problem occur in Safari? It may be WebKit related.

Comment: yep actually, same problem there, what webkit code should I include do you think?

Comment: solved it, it was an issue with webkit alright

Answer (score 0):

```
    .navbar .navbar-inner  .nav-collapse > ul > li:hover > span.sub-menu-response {
display: block;
background: #F8F8F8;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
border: 1px solid #9da3a7;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 0px !important; 
left:-92px;
}
```

it's because your left is -92px. change the left:-92x to 100px, you get what i'm saying.

Comment: That positioning is unrelated, as its a massive amount of content in the `span` (which I deleted for readability sakes), but thanks anyway